# In VB.net datestring + "-23.59.59.999" working in VS2003 not in VS2008 or VS2010

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, iis, code-behind

Hi All The Below code is working fine in Visual Studio 2003 but after i converted the solution to VS2008 the Below is giving error. Please Help me to fix the issue

code:

```
Dim strToDate As string
strToDate = "2013-02-06"

Dim dateFromSelect, dateToSelect, dateToSelectEnd, dateFromSelectStart As DateTime

dateToSelectEnd = strToDate + "-23:59:59.9999999"
```

Error

```
Conversion from string "2013-02-06-23:59:59.9999999" to type 'Date' is not valid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is

```
dateToSelectEnd = strToDate + "-23:59:59.9999999"
```

it should be

```
dateToSelectEnd = strToDate + " 23:59:59.9999999"
```

Comment: i agree but my expected out for the above code is Expected Output  is   #2/6/2013 11:59:59 PM#

Comment: then... when you use your date to pass it as string... you shoud do something like: mydate.ToString("M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt");